# Mac Terminal: "Initializing jdb ..." on start up

Tags: macos, terminal, jvm, jdb

As soon as I start the terminal on my Mac, I get the message "Initializing jdb ..." and it remains in this state until I terminate the process manually with a Ctrl+C. The other option is to start a JVM at on particular port and attach the jdb to that port. But subsequent windows of the terminal still results in the same "Initializing jdb ...". This has been occurring only recently on my machine.

Can someone throw some light on how I can stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be (directly or indirectly) invoking `jdb` in one of your shell startup scripts, like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, which run every time you create a new terminal. Don't do that. Remove that command (or commands) from your shell startup file(s) and invoke `jdb` manually when you want to start using it.

If there's some non-trivial code for starting `jdb`, wrap it in a shell function to make it convenient to invoke.

If it's your goal to have `jdb` always running, use a `launchd` job to start it at login instead of using Terminal to start it.